# Div with overflow:auto disappears

Tags: css

I have a wrapper div with a height of 600px and a width of 900px

Inside it there are 2 divs

The first is floated left with the below style

```
#left{
height : 100%;
width : 600px;
overflow:hidden;
float : left;
}
```

The second one is not floated, so that it can occupy the rest of the space and the style is

```
#right{
height : 100%;
overflow : auto;
margin-left : 600px;
}
```

The above design is meant to create a 2 column layout with a fixed height. The html I used is

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="left">
    <img id="main-image" src="/some/image"/>
  </div>
  <div id="right"></div>
  <br clear="left"/>
</div>
```

The thing is that Opera (v 10.01) and Safari (v. 4.0.3) do not display the right div.

When I remove the overflow:auto, however they do.

I cannot figure out why. Any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't want your margin left to be equal to your left column just because it's floated. That's usually a trick we use when it's *absolutely positioned*, not floated. Try that and it might just clear up.

What you have is most likely the right-hand div being pushed down out of view by its content plus margin. With `overflow:auto` it might be that scrollbars are being introduced and that triggers some additional resizing...don't know without more markup and CSS to look at. Best of luck!

Comment: DN

You are absolutely right man.

Removing the margin-left did it.

Now, the layout is the same across all of them

Thanks a lot

Comment: You are quite welcome. Would you mind clicking the checkmark next to my answer so it's registered as accepted?